# Partition problems : HDD seen twice

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, mint

I am a litle to no experienced with linux, so please be kind :).

I have a problem with all linux distributions.What i am trying to do is just install Ubuntu/Mint. Same problem on all.
What exactly my problem is?

As my english is not so good, i will explain what steps i follow to install linux:

- Make  a bootable USB then plug it in the computer.
- Partition the HDD : New partition table > EXT4 270 gigs volume
  mounted on "/", swap double as ram = 24gigs.
- Install. Everything goes fine.
- Click reboot when install is finished, but it hangs. Screen is black,
  no signal, but the
- PC is  still running.
- Reset the PC, everything starts normally.

Now, in Mint *same problem as on Ubuntu* , i can see 2 partitions, even if i didn't make 2. One is "Samsung SJ3200AAJS" or something like it, and "Filesystem".
Clicking on "Samsung..." partition shows me an error :"Cannot mount file".
Right click > properties > every info is "UNKNOWN", capacity, mountpoint, etc.

Gparted shows only 1 partition and a swap space.
I tried several times, creating a single partition with no swap. Nothing, same issue.
Tried replacing the HDD, same issue.

Why is this happening? I am very frustrated.

My pc's specs : 
4GB x3 trichannel DDR3 RAM

- XEON 5550 processor
- 2x GTX 480 Hair-driers
- 1000W PSU
- Motherboard : Aspire M7721
- Crappy 320 HDD.

PS: If you need any more informations, please reply and i will post it ASAP.

fdisk -l:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 320.1 GB, 320072933376 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 38913 cylinders, total 625142448 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00086642

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1            2046     7999487     3998721    5  Extended
/dev/sda2   *     7999488   625141759   308571136   83  Linux
/dev/sda5            2048     7999487     3998720   82  Linux swap / Solaris

Disk /dev/sdb: 15.5 GB, 15518924800 bytes // THIS IS MY USB TOSHIBA 16GIGS DRIVE
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 1886 cylinders, total 30310400 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00399248

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *        2048    30310399    15154176    c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)
```

fstab:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=b9c91b0e-640c-468f-89c1-11d8353648d9 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=66e344e1-4895-4bfb-8bbf-0f565feff8cd none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Comment: Can you add the output of `sudo fdisk -l`?

Comment: Can you edit your question by adding the content of `/etc/fstab`?

Comment: Here you go. Sorry for the late response, i fell asleep last night..